# My script to switch between walking and running animation wont work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

[image]I am working on a script to switch between animations (look at the screenshot to better understand) and the script is crude but it mostly does the job. The problem is that when you go to (Walk -> WalkToSprint) the WalkToSprint boolean stays active when it should deactivate which makes the animations go in a loop.

```
void Update()
{
     // this section is for walking and running
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        anim.SetBool("Walk", true);
        anim.SetBool("SprintToWalk", true);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            anim.SetBool("WalkToSprint", true);
            anim.SetBool("Idle", true);
            anim.SetBool("SprintToWalk", false);


        }
    }
   // end section

   //this section is for sprinting then to walking
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {    
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            anim.SetBool("Sprint", true);
            anim.SetBool("Walk", false);
            anim.SetBool("Idle", false);
            anim.SetBool("SprintToWalk", false);
        }
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////// this section is the key up code.

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W))
    {
        anim.SetBool("Walk", false);
        anim.SetBool("Sprint", false);
        anim.SetBool("Idle", false);
        anim.SetBool("WalkToSprint", true);
        anim.SetBool("SprintToWalk", false);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        anim.SetBool("Idle", false);
        anim.SetBool("WalkToSprint", false);
        anim.SetBool("SprintToWalk", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not understanding your code here. Are there 2 separate attempts, four, or something else?

Comment: @Draco18s are you referring to the code below the /////? That is seperating the keydown and the keyup function.

Comment: Oh okay. I will upload a screenshot separating each section of code

Comment: Do not post screenshots of code. However your comment helped me figure out that this is in fact meant to be one block of code. You have 2 identical statement blocks: `if(W && LeftShift)` and `if(LeftShift && W)` that have different contents. Additionally you should include your animation state machine.

Comment: @Draco18s The first one on the top half of /// is the walk and walk to run. The other is for sprinting then going to walking. I will add comments to the code and upload a screenshot of the animator controller.

Answer (score 1):

## Your state machine is wrong

[image: Picture of issue]

Note that your "walk to sprint" state is completely and utterly incapable of sending the animation *to the sprint state.* This might not be your only problem, however, but this is almost certainly the source of the infinite loop problem as the state machine is constantly sent back to Walk after being in WalkToSprint and never able to reach the Sprint state.

I would also advise reworking your logic code, because the section labeled "for sprinting then to walking" requires that the user initiate a press **down** on the W key (something that they can't do if they're already sprinting, because Sprinting is holding both shift and W in the down position, which also calls tells the animation to go idle `anim.SetBool("Idle", true);`!).

Comment: @Draco28s The reason for that is that there are 2 different animations for them. WalkToSprint has the animation adjust from walking to running while sprint just goes from idle to running.

Comment: Then fix your state machine so you don't have all those extra transitions. If you can't go from `Walk` to `Sprint` then you don't need that arrow. And your code is still painfully awkward and almost certainly wrong. For example, it doesn't care what state your animator is currently in when handling key presses.

Comment: Unity has a built-in way to deal with [blending animations](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-BlendTree.html)

Comment: @Draco18s I just figured out a workaround that I should have earlier (i guess I stayed up to late). I will post the code and screenshot in an answer in case it helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to change the animation of sprinting so I could remove WalkToSprint and that left me with a straight shot.
[image]

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        anim.SetBool("Walk", true);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            anim.SetBool("Sprint", true);
            anim.SetBool("Idle", true);
        }
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////


    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W))
    {
        anim.SetBool("Walk", false);
        anim.SetBool("Idle", false);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        anim.SetBool("Sprint", false);
    }
}
```